# mysql remote connect

Tags: php, mysql

Having troubles with this and I'm not sure why..
I'm trying to access a mysql database from another server.

I changed the my.cnf file (uncommented the bind-address to access from all):

```
port=3306
#bind-address=12.34.56.78
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# skip-networking
```

I set up the user, and the user works: (I know "ALL" is bad, but I'm just trying to get this to work...)

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'MY_DATABASE'.* TO 'MY_USERNAME'@'12.34.56.78' IDENTIFIED BY 'MY_PASSWORD';
```

I restarted mysql:
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart

I opened up the port from within plesk, and then restarted the whole server. (It's a VPS)

now, when I try and telnet from my desktop, it connects, shows a bunch of garbage text then closes the connection 5 seconds later.

I'm trying to connect with php:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("DOMAIN.COM:3306", "MY_USERNAME", "MY_PASSWORD") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
```

?>

and I get a "Can't connect to MySQL server" error after a 10 second timeout.

The log files are empty, only showing when I restarted mysqld.

Any ideas or tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you connect by means other than PHP using the same user/pass?

Comment: I tried putty using the telnet feature and it just opens and closes

Comment: Then it sounds like the problem is your mysql server is misconfigured

Comment: I think this link http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html can help you

Comment: Thanks. I followed everything on that page to a T, but still times out, and telnet shows that garbage text then closes the connection

Comment: Well Im at a loss, I was reading some stuff that says SELinux may be to blame, but it's disabled. Looks like Im calling the VPS Provider tomorrow.... yaaaay... lol. Thanks guys.